# What is a secure data model in Firestore for location based app?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a location-based app. People can see other people in 10 miles radius. I have data stored which are public like names and some which are private like latitude and longitude and a geohash. How can I create a model for this data to minimize reads and maximize security and maximize performace. Currently I have a `Users` collection and documents for each user inside that collection which contain all public and private data. My current code looks like this

```
db.collection("Users").whereField("geohash", >=: geohash_prefix)
.whereField("geohash", <=: "geohash_prefix" + "~").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
         if err != nil{
            print("\(err!.localizedDescription)")
         }else{
                if querySnapshot!.isEmpty{
                    return completion(arr_of_users)
                }
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let d = document.data()
                    let isWithin = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (d["loc"] as! GeoPoint).latitude, longitude: (d["location"] as! GeoPoint).longitude).isWithin(min: self.MBR.1, max: self.MBR.0) //just used for filtering documents not in radius
                    if !isWithin{ //skip all docs not in range
                         continue
                    }
                    nearPeople.append([d["firstName"] as! String,  d["lastName"] as! String])
                }
                    

}
```

So, you can see that to display the first and last names to the user of everyone who is in a 10 miles radius, I have to send over location data to the client which isn't safe. I also cannot separate it into a subcollection because I need to get names and other public info which will require a second query (more reads). I know google cloud functions is fully insulated from the client, so is that my only option? Will that sacrifice performance? Also, I am sure this type of app is not uncommon, what is the most common approach to this?

Comment: Hey Kunal. I tried to clarify below. Did you get a chance to read it? Does this better explain why you can't secure query this data directly from the application code?

Comment: Hi Frank. Yes, I am now using Cloud Functions to do the querying on geohashes. You also mentioned that a user can change their location to query from anywhere, but is that issue now solved since they cannot get the location data since it is protected by the cloud function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said on your previous question: to be able to query on certain data, the user needs to be able to read that data. And since Firestore can't perform your `isWithin(min: self.MBR.1, max: self.MBR.0)` condition on the server, that means they will at the very least need to have access to all data within `db.collection("Users").whereField("geohash", >=: geohash_prefix).whereField("geohash", <=: "geohash_prefix" + "~")`.

If you want to restrict access to a specific set of geohashes in the collection, your security rules will have to relate the position around which you query to the the corresponding geohashes. While I'm not saying it is not possible to do so, looking at this [implementation in geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/3a393ea04f34a462657ff672eb6ec0c938e36364/src/utils.ts#L182-L233) makes it seem at the very least far from trivial.

Your most direct approach is to do this in Cloud Functions indeed.

---

I'm not sure what most other apps do, but it may help to realize that you also have no way to ensure that the user is sending their actual location to the database. So even if you give the perfect results for the location/range, nothing stops them from repeatedly querying with a different location to still get all of your user's data.